# Как обновить директорию, в которой находишься, но которая была удалена в другом шелле?

Tags: linux, c, bash, администрирование, makefile

Я нахожусь в директории билда `build` в одном шелле, могу делать `ls` файлов и прочее. В другом шелле запускаю полный ребилд, в течение которого директория полностью удаляется, создаётся заново и файлы с теми же названиями появляются в ней. Однако сейчас в первом шелле я не могу ничего сделать с этими файлами в директории. Необходимо перезайти в неё. Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы не надо было перезаходить? Как автоматически обновить первый шелл? Все названия файлов и директорий остаются прежними, но на самом деле новые.

Comment: `cd && cd -` - первое что в голову пришло. Ещё `cd \`pwd\``.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy но это и есть перезаход, а я хочу без перезахода, т.е. без ввода доп. комманд в 1 шелле

Comment: Проще сделать rebuild удаляя не сам сборочный каталог, а его содержимое. Вы так можете?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy у меня есть готовый докерфайл, который генерит свежую директорию `build` с исполняемыми файлами, а в другом шелле после каждого ребилда я смотрю свойства полученных файлов. Мб и можно где-то настроить, чтобы в существующую директорию писал файлы, не знаю, но надо будет этот файл править, а по хорошему я могу править только сорсы программы.

Comment: Если не может поправить докер, то запускаете докер, затем перебрасываете содержимое нового `build` туда где вам будет удобно с ним работать. Никакой головной боли.

Comment: да просто не делайте текущим каталог, который регулярно удаляете. и проблемы обращения к файлам в этом каталоге не будет.